# Does attack speed improve main attack of Artificer?

Tags: risk-of-rain-2

So far, Artificer is the only RoR2 character, who has cooldown on primary attack ability. This makes my wondering, how attack speed improve Artificer capabilites. Does it decrease cooldown?

Comment: I haven't tested this near thoroughly enough to post as an actual answer, but from what I can tell, it didn't seem to help.   If it _does_ decrease that cooldown, the decrease in cooldown is nowhere near as substantial as the increase in attack speed.  From my memory, it increased the travel velocity of the shots as well; which was helpful, but not too helpful, because the decreased downtime between shots means you use up your charges much quicker when you have stacked syringes, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, attack speed will not lower the cooldown. Attack speed will increase the rate at which the bolts are fired once they are charged. However, to increase the rate at which the bolts charge, you'll need something like an Alien Head to decrease the cooldown.

If you only build Soldier's Syringes on Artificer, your rate of fire of the primary ability will still be hard capped by the cooldown.

Comment: Well, it seems to be the case. Once of the examples why this game would be better in coop - you just get items, useless for your character, in single player.

Comment: Ya, generally you try to match a build as close as possible and use shrines of order or 3D printers to trade in anything you don’t need.